# iOS 6, SDWebImage success/failure block error. Incompatible Block pointer types?

Tags: ios6, sdwebimage

I am lazy loading an image via `setImageWithURL` into a `UIImageView` embedded in a `UIScrollView`.

Since this is fora photo gallery, I am trying to use the 'success' code block to set `myScrollView`'s contentSize and the imageview's frame after it completely loads so it can zoom properly.

Problem is, I keep getting a strange error using 'success' in my call. If I comment out the success/failure portion of the method, it works but I can't tell when the image finishes loading, and thus cannot size the container correctly so it zooms properly... help?

Error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending `'void (^)(UIImage *__strong)'` to parameter of type `'SDWebImageSuccessBlock'` (aka `'void (^)(UIImage *__strong, BOOL)'`)

Is the error I receive on the following code @ the line beginning with `success:^`...

Code:

```
 [_ivFullSize setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[currentPhoto PhotoAbsoluteLocation]]
placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"]
success:^(UIImage *image){
                         [DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
                         self.myScrollView.contentSize = self.ivFullSize.image.size;
                         self.ivFullSize.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,     self.ivFullSize.image.size.width, self.ivFullSize.image.size.height);
                     }
                     failure:^(NSError *error){
                                    [DejalBezelActivityView removeViewAnimated:YES];
                     }];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have run into the same problem recently, after upgrading the SDWebImage version to the latest one. I have no idea why this is happening, but I would assume that it is an undocumented change in the function block. Basically the function is returning an additional boolean parameter.

So without knowing the reason of the problem, I have solved it by simply adding a new boolean parameter to the block. Instead of writing

```
...
success:^(UIImage *image)
{
  ... do something with image
}
failure:^(NSError *error)
...
```

I used the following:

```
...
success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL dummy)
{
  ... do something with image and ignore dummy
}
failure:^(NSError *error)
...
```

This removes the raised error but still leaves questions on the nature of the additional boolean variable. Any additional documentation or clarification would be greatly appreciated. The documentation [here](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Categories/UIImageView+WebCache.html#//api/name/setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:success:failure:) still refers to the old version.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out as well. Forgot to post. Thanks!